# To convert an Ascii character into its symbol in java

Tags: java

How can I convert an ASCII code into its symbol :

For example- I have a Character array List and i am using Character.get(index) to get each element of the array list. Suppose I get a ASCII code 49 as first element  which is ASCII code for symbol '1'.

```
Character.get(index);
```

Now how can convert the Character.get(index) element into its corresponding symbol value.Like here I want to convert 49 to 1.

Comment: just do a cast: `(char) index`

Comment: Basically, you have it.  49 is the decimal value for an entry in the ASCII table whose glyph is `1`.  You can, however, use `Character.digit((char)49, 10)` to retrieve numeric value 1, corresponding to the usual interpretation of that glyph.

Answer (score 3):

Use `(char) index;`. Just cast it to a char.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 49;
    System.out.println((char) i);
}
```

prints

> 1

Actually, you don't even need to cast it. I assume an implicit cast ([Narrowing/widening a primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)) is available since this also works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char i = 49;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

prints

> 1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this works in java, but give it a try:

```
char c = (char)49;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the ASCII Code to its symbol then you can do it just using simple casting like

---

```
**`System.out.println((char)65);`**
```

---

like wise you can use in your code...

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 49;
System.out.format("%c", i);
```

or use casting

```
int i = 49;
char c = (char) i;
System.out.println(c);
```

Both Outputs

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast the elements if you defined it as `ArrayList<Character>`.

the `char` type will give you the symbol by its code, and vise versa. You don't need to extra coding to it.

For example, you have:

```
ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
char c = 49;
list.add(c);
list.add('b');
// You can get the symbol or code easily as follows:
char a = list.get(0);
int b = list.get(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `ArrayList` that is declared like so:

```
ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

...and you are using `list.get(i)` to retrieve your elements from the list:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { // rewrite with foreach
    Character c = list.get(i);
    // other code
}
```

...you should already have the character symbol coming back in `c`.

If you have an `ArrayaList` that is declared with `Integer` instead, then you should be able to use the same value, except you're casting the result:

```
Character c = Character.valueOf(((char)list.get(i).intValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:- This will give output as character 'a' you can change i to get all ascii values.
    `int i  = 97; system.out.println((char)i);`