# String to Value Conversion Clarification

Tags: java, string, ascii

I have come across a small logic in one of my applications, Can't seem to figure out how the value is being generated.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String name="Rupesh";
    int c = name.charAt(0);
    char c1 = name.charAt(0);
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(c1);
}
```

SOP(C1) is expected. But what is SOP(C2). How can we convert from Char to Int? What does the value exactly mean? Is it ASCII value?

Thanks!

Comment: A `char` *is* an integer.  It just tends to have fewer bits than other integer types.  The value of `c` and `c1` should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can we convert from Char to Int?

typecast

> What does the value exactly mean?

82 is the ASCII value for letter R uppercase.

> Is it ASCII value?

Yes

Answer (score 0):

Converting a `char` to `int` will return the ASCII value, yes. Quick [referral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432798/to-convert-an-ascii-character-into-its-symbol-in-java/19432851#19432851) to a similar question earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it gives the [ASCII](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/ascii.html) values

```
System.out.println((char) c);
System.out.println((int) c1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A char can be implicitly cast into an int because an int is bigger (32 bits versus 16). A char in Java is a 16-bit Unicode character. While the first 128 characters of Unicode are the same as ASCII, Unicode contains many, many more characters.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html for Java data types.